# Fazer este grid com Flexbox

Tags: flexbox

Pessoal estou tendo uma grande dificuldade para criar com o Flexbox este grid, conforme a imagem abaixo. Eu preciso que ele fique sem tamanho fixo pois quando as imagens forem vistas no celular ficara na mesma posição somente menor.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: coloque o código que está tentando em sua pergunta

Comment: @MagicHat eu nem sei por onde começar todos os videos que eu vi só tratam de colunas ou linhas uniformes. Não achei nada que tenha uma foto grade e duas menores usando a mesma altura da foto maior.

Comment: Uma coisa é a estrutura, outra é o que ela vai conter...Essa proporção que vc menciona entre o desktop e o celular, não acredito ser o ideal, pois o mobile tem um estilo vertical,,,

Comment: @MagicHat então eu sei. Mas o cliente me pediu assim. Ele quer uma galeria de fotos igual a esta que ele viu num template do WP, [link](https://colorlib.com/unite/gallery). Ai quando vc muda para mobile ela simplesmente encolhe na proporção.

Comment: Saquei...Mas não tenho certeza se o flexbox resolve isso, creio que tem de ser com mediaquerie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você vai precisar criar um wrapper para englobar as imagens. Depois dividir a imagem da direita e da esquerda em seus respectivos containers.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <figure>
    <div class="img-grid double"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/344x210/574357/fff" /><img src="http://dummyimage.com/344x210/574357/fff" /></div>
    <div class="img-grid single"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/660x440/445157/fff" /></div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Logo após isso, dê o width que você quer para seu wrapper. Tenha certeza de usar max-width e não width, assim ele irá acompanhar a largura da tela.

```
.wrapper
  max-width 1024px //site content width
  margin 1em auto 0 auto
```

E para o resto:

```
figure
  max-width 100% 
  display flex
  justify-content space-between

.img-grid
  display flex
  flex-direction column // coloca as iamgens uma em cima da outra
  justify-content space-between

.img-grid.double
  flex 0 33%
  min-width 0 // FireFox hack

.img-grid.single
  flex 0 64%
  min-width 0 // FireFox hack

img
  max-width 100%
```

Aqui está um exemplo para você testar. Faça algumas alterações para ver como tudo funciona. Espero ter ajudado!

http://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/XNOBWy

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/92152)

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pelo auxílio, editei a resposta!